# Creating an MJPEG Viewer Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asyncsocket, mjpeg

I'm trying to make a MJPEG viewer in Objective C but I'm having a bunch of issues with it.

First off, I'm using AsyncSocket(http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) which lets me connect to the host.

Here's what I got so far

```
NSLog(@"Ready");
asyncSocket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
//http://kamera5.vfp.slu.se/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi
NSError *err = nil;
if(![asyncSocket connectToHost:@"kamera5.vfp.slu.se" onPort:80 error:&err])
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", err);
}
```

then in the didConnectToHost method:

```
 - (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port{
NSLog(@"Accepted client %@:%hu", host, port);


NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://kamera5.vfp.slu.se/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    //set headers
NSString *_host = [NSString stringWithFormat:host];
[request addValue:_host forHTTPHeaderField: @"Host"];

NSString *KeepAlive = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"300"];
[request addValue:KeepAlive forHTTPHeaderField: @"Keep-Alive"];

NSString *connection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"keep-alive"];
[request addValue:connection forHTTPHeaderField: @"Connection"];


//get response
NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;  
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];  
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error]; 

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
            //here you get the response
}
```

}

This calls the MJPEG stream, but it doesn't call it to get more data. What I think its doing is just loading the first chunk of data, then disconnecting.

Am I doing this totally wrong or is there light at the end of this tunnel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the mjpeg in a UiWebView, it should be able to play it natively.

Assuming you have a UiWebView called "myWebView", something like this should work:

```
NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://kamera5.vfp.slu.se/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi"]];
[myWebView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I figured I could do that. I just thought there was a better way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: IMO there's no use complicating your life when the simplest way might get the job done. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is that webkit never relase the data, so after a while it explode.

Comment: any proofe of that? did a test with 5 mjpegs and memory usage did not grow within 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

That would probably best be done with JavaScript since there isn't a good way to communicate with UIWebView otherwise.